# Properly implement custom IAuthenticationManager ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I've got my own implementation of `UserManager`, `UserStore`, `ApplicationUser` and `SignInManager`.

The `SigninManager` and `UserManager` are registered like this:

```
inApp.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
inApp.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

Now I'd like to implement my own `AuthenticationManager`. How do I register it? Same as `SignInManager` doesn't work apparently.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: @theycallmemorty Unfortunately I didn't. I ended up without using a custom AuthenticationManager.

Comment: Welp, that sounds terrible, thanks for the reply.